# highcharts-export Server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when running the application under Tomcat or Jetty

Tags: highcharts

I follow the guide : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

```
Windows : 7
JDK : 8.0.20
Maven : 3.2.3
Apache Tomcat : 8.0.12
Highcharts-export-web : Version f97fbcf5f0d8cc72942a3b680e0e2a187ba1aedf and v4.0.4
```

I put the war into the webapps folder and I start the server. The server does not start

I have tried on several versions (checkout from 5 November 2014 and the last tag v4.0.4). It produces the same output
I have tried jetty version too, and this is the same result.

Output of the startup.bat

```
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:23.756 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
    er.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performa
    nce in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\devtoo
    ls\jdks\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C
    :\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\devtools\Microchip\mplabc32\v2.02\bin;C:\d
    evtools\Microchip\MPLAB C30\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System
    32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro
    soft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\T
    ools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Progra
    m Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Serv
    er\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSSh
    ell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\
    PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\
    Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\
    Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platfor
    m Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power
    Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\
    Best Practices Analyzer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Perform
    ance Toolkit\;C:\devtools\Microchip\MPLAB C32 Suite\bin;C:\Program Files\Microso
    ft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\devtools\Git\cmd;C:\devtools\Git\bin;C:\Program
     Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\devtools\adt-bundle-windows-x86-2
    0140624\sdk\tools;C:\devtools\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\devtools\jdks\jdk1.8.0_20\
    bin;C:\Program Files\Symantec.cloud\PlatformAgent\;C:\devtools\apache-maven-3.2.
    3\bin;;.
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.006 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini
    tializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.075 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.
    getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.078 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini
    tializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.081 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.
    getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load I
    nitialization processed in 651 ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.110 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.st
    artInternal DÚmarrage du service Catalina
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.110 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.sta
    rtInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.12
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.158 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployWAR DÚploiement de l'archive C:\devtools\apache-tomcat-8.0.12
    -Highcharts\webapps\highcharts-export-web.war de l'application web
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:24.177 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.sta
    rtup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting
    property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
    [ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 04:14:26] (ContextLoader.java:initWebApplicationC
    ontext:307) Context initialization failed
    **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**
            at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
            at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactor
    y.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
            at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFacto
    ry.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
            at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactor
    y.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getIm
    ports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getIm
    ports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getIm
    ports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doPro
    cessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.proce
    ssConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse
    (ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcesso
    r.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcesso
    r.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invoke
    BeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
    h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebA
    pplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationConte
    xt(ContextLoader.java:283)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
    zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
    t.java:4751)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
    t.java:5175)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
    .java:724)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:70
    0)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)

            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
    1704)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:26.930 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core
    .StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:27.028 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core
    .StandardContext.startInternal Erreur de dÚmarrage du contexte [/highcharts-expo
    rt-web] suite aux erreurs prÚcÚdentes
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:27.040 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\devtools\apache-
    tomcat-8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\highcharts-export-web.war has finished in 2á882
     ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:27.041 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployWAR DÚploiement de l'archive C:\devtools\apache-tomcat-8.0.12
    -Highcharts\webapps\richCharts.war de l'application web
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:28.470 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.faces.config.Confi
    gureListener.contextInitialized Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for contex
    t '/richCharts'
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:28.476 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.faces.config.Co
    nfigureListener.contextInitialized JSF1059: WARNING!  The com.sun.faces.verifyOb
    jects feature is to aid developers not using tools.  It shouldn''t be enabled if
     using an IDE, or if this application is being deployed for production as it wil
    l impact application start times.
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.Chamel
    eonRenderKitFactory).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:29.403 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.faces.spi.Injectio
    nProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations pr
    esent.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annota
    tions processed.
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.062 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\devtools\apache-
    tomcat-8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\richCharts.war has finished in 4á020 ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.064 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory DÚploiement du rÚpertoire C:\devtools\apache-tomcat
    -8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\docs de l'application web
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.088 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\devtools
    \apache-tomcat-8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\docs has finished in 24 ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.088 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory DÚploiement du rÚpertoire C:\devtools\apache-tomcat
    -8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\examples de l'application web
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.525 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\devtools
    \apache-tomcat-8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\examples has finished in 436 ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.525 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory DÚploiement du rÚpertoire C:\devtools\apache-tomcat
    -8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\host-manager de l'application web
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.566 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\devtools
    \apache-tomcat-8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\host-manager has finished in 41 ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.567 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory DÚploiement du rÚpertoire C:\devtools\apache-tomcat
    -8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\manager de l'application web
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.595 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\devtools
    \apache-tomcat-8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\manager has finished in 28 ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.596 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory DÚploiement du rÚpertoire C:\devtools\apache-tomcat
    -8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\ROOT de l'application web
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.620 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
    p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\devtools
    \apache-tomcat-8.0.12-Highcharts\webapps\ROOT has finished in 25 ms
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.626 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
    arting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.637 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
    arting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    05-Nov-2014 16:14:31.640 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start
    Server startup in 7558 ms
```

Do you have a stable version which does not contain this problem ?

Comment: A fix is available here : https://github.com/svanacker/highcharts.com/tree/1

The issue is described here :
https://github.com/svanacker/highcharts.com/issues/1

It's due to spring-version and cglib version which is too old (cglib was removed).

Comment: The above fix works well for both JDK 1.7 and JDK 8.0